# Voltar repositório para o estado anterior

Tags: git, versionamento

Tenho um projeto que utilizamos GIT para versionamento. Porém, um dos programadores subiu uma versão errada para o servidor remoto, deu `commit`, `push` e vários `commits` e `pushs`.

Aí o site deu erro. Tentamos `git checkout <commit numero>`, `git revert` e nada!

Quero desfazer todas as alterações que ele fez em determinada data para o que era antes, e entender como desfazer essas alterações após um usuário dar um `push` no servidor.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, dê um `git log` para recuperar o hash de todos os últimos commits. Por exemplo:

```
git log -n 20 # lista os últimos 20 commits
```

Nessa listagem, copie o hash do último commit estável. Em seguida, dê um `git rebase` para reescrever o histórico de commits:

```
git rebase -i <hash do último commit estável>
```

(atenção: esse comando literalmente reescreve o histórico de commits, então tome cuidado!)

Então você entrará numa tela a qual lista todos os commits entre o `HEAD` e o hash que você escolheu. Descarte os commits errados simplesmente excluindo a linha referente aos commits.

Finalmente, basta dar um `git push -f` para subir a reescrita do histórico para o repositório remoto.

Nos servidor, basta apenas dar um `git pull --rebase` para buscar as últimas alterações do repositório.

Comment: É altamente desaconselhável apagar commits que já foram publicados. O ideal é reverte-los, nao apagá-los.